# simple xml and element with same name but different namespace

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

Hi I'm using this library for xml parsing http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#state

how can I parse a document like this?

```
<atom:link href="http://address.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link>http://address.com</link>
```

I keep getting "duplicate annotation of name 'link' " ...
I tried this way:

```
@Root
@NamespaceList({
@Namespace(reference="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/", prefix="content"),
@Namespace(reference="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/", prefix="wfw"),
@Namespace(reference="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", prefix="dc"),
@Namespace(reference="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix="atom"),
@Namespace(reference="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/", prefix="sy"),
})
public class Rss {
   @Element
   private Channel channel;
```

My element:

```
@Element
private String link;

@Element(name="link")
@Namespace(reference="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
private RssLink rssLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining the namespace?

In XML that's done by setting an attribute `xmlns:atom="any://unique/url/here"`; the best place to set it is on a parent element common to all children - typically the root element.

In your library, [see related documentation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#namesoace).

Comment: I do it... @Root
@NamespaceList({
@Namespace(reference="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/", prefix="content"),
@Namespace(reference="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/", prefix="wfw"),
@Namespace(reference="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", prefix="dc"),
@Namespace(reference="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix="atom"),
@Namespace(reference="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/", prefix="sy"),
})
public class Rss {, and for element, @Element(name="link")
 @Namespace(reference="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",prefix="atom")
 private RssLink rssLink;

Comment: I got the same problem and cant find a solution. I also can't get the solution out the documentation